# How to set up an X server to accept connections from my main computer

Tags: linux, xorg

I have computer 1 and computer 2. Computer 1 has KVM (keyboard video mouse), and computer 2 just has video. I want to use computer 2 as a remote display for computer 1, and nothing more. Using ssh -x user@host merely displays programs from computer 2 on computer 1's display, which is the exact opposite of what I need. I read around on other, somewhat similar questions, involving something called ".Xauthority" which is supposed 'cookie' for the X server, however it is vague. How would I go about with displaying programs from computer 1 on computer 2, using the X server, without using SSH?

Answer (score 1):

### X On the Network

While there is a small performance hit for connecting to a X server via TCP, it is much less than the performance lost of tunnelling X through an encrypted (ssh) TCP connection. For 2D and light 3D graphics applications it should be fine on a LAN (e.g. 100Mbps / 1Gbps Ethernet) which I believe is the case in the posed question.

In the X Window System the [**server**](http://www.x.org/wiki/guide/concepts/#xisclientserver) is the system offering the display, so in your case that would be computer 2 (video only).

One problem is X normally expects the server to also be where the user is sitting / operating from, so it expects the keyboard and mouse to also connected to the server. The [evdev](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/evdev.4.html) ([Linux](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt)) or possibly [Xinput2](http://www.x.org/wiki/guide/extensions/#xinput2) input drivers might might offer a means to utilize a remote keyboard and mouse, I'm not sure.

By default the X server no longer listens on the TCP port, [so it must be enabled](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/Xserver.1.xhtml). That said, it should most often be done *in cooperation* with your window display manager (XDM, GDM, KDM, etc.) which have various ways to enable it. Consult your distributions' documentation for the window manager you are using (KDE, GNOME, Xfce, etc.). Otherwise you can simply delete the parameters `-nolisten tcp` from the script that launches the [Xserver](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/Xserver.1.xhtml).

Then you need to configure the [Xsecurity](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man7/Xsecurity.7.xhtml) to enable [sane security](http://www.x.org/wiki/guide/communication/) between the client and server.

Then you should be able to launch applications on computer 1 (let's call it `host1` for simplicity), and display them back to computer 2 (affectionately referred to as `host2`).

```
user@host1$ xclock -d host2:0.0
```

or

```
user@host1$ xclock -d host2
```

or (assuming Bourne-like shell)

```
user@host1$ export DISPLAY=host2:0.0
user@host1$ xclock &
```

---

### Alternative Solution

As I am not cofident you will be able to successfully use X11 as you wish, I will echo and comment on @user2986553's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/835833/1200). I believe that you may wish to use a remote desktop connect, such as VNC.

With most VNC servers and clients, you can export a display as "view-only" as without the ability to take *control* of the mouse or keyboard, which would be suitable in your setup. I have seen it used for remote presentation system across a campus-wide network. Computer 1 would be running the VNC server, while computer 2 would be using a VNC client, with view-only privileged.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, that connecting remotely to X-server has bad performance.
You can set up an vnc  server(it is like RDP on Windows ) on computer 1 and connect with computer 2 over VNC.
Here is [example](http://linuxconfig.org/configuring-vnc-server-access-on-a-redhat-linux) for RedHat linux.